# Как использовать scottyab securePreferences

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

На ГитХабе есть такой инструмент: https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences.

В описании использования все просто:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = new SecurePreferences(context, null, "my_custom_prefs.xml");
```

Мне студия говорит что не может распознать символ context.
Пытался Гуглить - безуспешно. Помогите, добрые люди  ))

Comment: [Что такое context](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/context.php). Поставьте `this` вместо `context`. А вообще, начинать обучение андроид лучше с основ, а не с библиотек.

Comment: Побывал ставить this - не получилось

Comment: Откуда вы этот код вызываете? Из фрагмента? Почитайте материал по ссылке, что я дал и сами сможете решить ваш вопрос. Тут ничего сложного нет.